# Display Text components inline and wrapped inside Views

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display `Text` components wrapped inside `View` components inline. With inline, I mean that the text should be displayed next to each other at all time. This is the best "solution" that I have atm:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
    <View>
        <Text>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Text>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>b</Text>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Text>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</Text>
    </View>
    {/* Possibly an icon, or text with a different lineheight...*/}
</View>
```

But it doesn't work all the time! This is what it renders out:

[image]

It does work when all strings are only one line long though.
Now, I know what is going on, a `View` is always a rectangle, thus in my example, the view that contains the first string is as wide as the first line of the letters a and as high as the two rows of letters a.
I am looking for a way around this, while still using `View`s. So something like this:

```
<Text>
    <Text>...</Text>
    <Text>...</Text>
</Text>
```

is unfortunately not the answer. It will not work in my use-case because I need to have the ability to display superscript, which appears to only be possible by changing the line height, and I would like to be able to add some inline icons (using react-native-vector-icons).

I have been struggling with this seemingly easy issue for way too long now, so at last this cry for help. Anyone has an idea? (If there is a way to display inline superscript, that'd also work, then I can nest `Text` components but I guess there isn't)

Comment: Hey do you want images to be inline with the text am I right?

Comment: @HaiderAli Yes, but not only images. Just Views in general

Comment: You can add Views in Text as parent vice versa but the problem is that they aren't inline?

Comment: @HaiderAli That does not work on Android, only on iOS.

Comment: If you do something like this it wont work on android?
<Text style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
        <Text>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>b</Text>
        <Text>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</Text>
        <Text>
          <Image
            style={{ height: 25, width: 25 }}
            resizeMode={'center'}
            source={require('./someImage.png')}
          />
        </Text>
        <Text>wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</Text>
      </Text>

Comment: @HaiderAli Not sure about an image, but it definitely does not work with Views

Comment: Im a little bit confused on what you are trying to achieve, Views will always be rectangles, can you somehow provide a UI example?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put text inside each other

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
   <Text>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdadasdadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>asdadasdab
     <Text>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</Text>
    </Text>
   </Text>
 </View>
```

Comment: As explained in the question, this is not a valid solution for me.

Comment: This solution is good enough if the styling you need to apply to your inline-element is stylable with Text, anything more complex (like OP's example) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block;` in the style section

Comment: That is unfortunately not supported in React Native which has different styling than React.

Comment: Try adding {{flex:1}}

Comment: Tried that in every possible component and with every single combination, no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the flex activator. This will do the trick:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>  
  <Text>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Text>
  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>b</Text>
  <Text>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</Text>
</View>
```

You have to specify when you're working with FlexBox layouts.

Comment: That is not the solution unfortunately. This does not prevent the `View` from always being rectangular.

Comment: So, I think I dont understood you well. Can you add a mock of what you're trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question was not clear. But that's what I understood from your question

```
<View style={{ flex: 1}}>  
   <Text>aaaaaaaaaaaa</Text>
   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "flex-start"}}>
       <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>b</Text>
       <Text>ccccccccccccccccccc</Text>
   </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out your solution with define multi-row.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <View style={styles.container}>
            <View ><Text >aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Text></View>
            <View ><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bbbbb</Text></View>
            <View ><Text >ccccc</Text></View>
        </View>;
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column'
    }
});
```

[image]
and you can hidden overflow text with below code

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        mytextvar :'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
        maxlimit:50
    };
}

render() {
    return <View style={styles.container}>
        <View ><Text >{((this.state.mytextvar).length > this.state.maxlimit) ?
            (((this.state.mytextvar).substring(0,this.state.maxlimit-3)) + '...') :
            this.state.mytextvar}</Text></View>
        <View ><Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bbbbb</Text></View>
        <View ><Text >ccccc</Text></View>
    </View>;
   }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
       flex: 1,
       flexDirection: 'column'
     }
});
```

[image]